# Joining query in access 2010

Tags: function, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I tried to join two query in access 2010.

Both query have names and month in number. one has assigned # of tasks and another have # closed. I want to join them so I can see how many assigned and closed for each person by each month. The query with # assigned has more rows.  I tried to left join with names since the query on the left is assigned and has more columns. But I cannot make it work because the row number is different and I cannot relate the month number together either. How can I join them together? Thank you in advance.

Query are Something like:

```
1.
Name   Month   # assigned 
John.      1.          7
Lee.       1.          8



2.
Name.  Month.  # closed. 
John.      1.          5
```

Want:

```
Name. Month  # assigned.  # closed
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given names of tables or columns you are going to have to substitute those in.

The below query will return all rows from Table1 and the matching Closed from Table2.

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.Month, Table1.Assigned, Table2.Closed
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Name = Table1.Name AND Table2.Month = Table1.Month;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is what I had before. Now I just cheked again and realize that in the list people can actually close more than they were assigned in a given month.... So i thought i was wrong before Sigh. Thank you for the reply again.

Comment: So can they close something in a month and not have something assigned?  That becomes a bit of an issue as Access does not support a Full Outer Join although there is a workaround of using the above with a UNION statement and then a right join version of the above.